# pythons' select.poll() method on Apple OSX

Tags: python, macos

I am currently using MAC OSX and realised that python's select.poll() is not supported.
I went through various discussions and realised that OSX python doesnot support poll() , 
and I then re-installed python using macports, changed $PATH and realised that select.poll()still returns the same error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_poll.py", line 14, in 
    poll = select.poll()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'

turns out, even macports doesnot support poll() anymore.

So, I then installed homebrew and same was the case.
 I can now run poll() only through the Ubuntu VM . 
Just wanted to know if anyone here could use select.poll() through macports/homebrew or any other method??
I am learning /understanding event based programming(using python) and it would be great if I can run poll() or related methods , before I move onto twisted.

also is there a substitute method what I can use instead of poll() ? is it select.select()??

Comment: ``select.poll()`` works for me. Python 2.7.5, OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: thanks for the response..i am running 10.8.4 .. , but is it default python that comes with OSX?

Comment: No, I installed this one with [``pyenv``](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) (which, in turn, is installed with ``homebrew``).

Comment: On OS/X, `select.poll` exists or not depending on the exact version of OSX you're running it with; it should not depend on the particular version of Python (as long as it's 2.7).  Are you running a very old OS/X (like 10.3)?  See http://bugs.python.org/issue1471761 .

Comment: Hi Bogdan- thanks for the confirmation. Also, Armin, as previously mentioned I am running 10.8.4. Right now I am just using python that comes with ubuntu.